# Escape curly braces in string.Format or string interpolation and a format specifier

Tags: c#

I have encountered a curious problem with string interpolation (also happens with string.Format).

I want to create a string in the form of {x} where x is any number. I know how to escape curly braces, and it works as intended, but only if I don't add a format specifier. I can "fix" it by adding a space between the first closing brace, but that changes the output string.

```
int i = 5
string a = $"{{{i}}}";    // creates {5}
string b = $"{{{i:D} }}"; // creates "{5 }"
string c = $"{{{i:D}}}";  // this is what I want, but creates "{D}", not "{5}" because the first two closing braces are interpreted as one escaped one and D} is interpreted as a custom format string
```

Is there a clean way to do this? (i.e. without hacks using Regex.Replace, or adding additional placeholders in the form of `$"{{{i:D}{"}"}"`)

Comment: No repro. `string c = $"{{{i:D}}}"; ` returns `{5}`

Comment: And `$"{{{i:D2}}}"; ` returns `{05}`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos FWIW [I can repro in linqpad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVllk.png), which makes this even more intriguing - potentially a breaking change between versions somewhere along the way...?

Comment: @JamesThorpe that's what I used and got `{5}` and `{05}`. I use Linqpad 6 for .Net Core

Comment: This issue was fixed for either C# 8 or .NET core. Not sure which. You can repro in LINQPad 5, not in 6.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Reproduced in [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7Oqzk3)

Comment: Yeah I'm still on full framework linqpad 5 here.

Comment: @Sweeper which runtime, language version? Obviously it's a version issue, not a Linqpad issue

Comment: Looks like it's an issue just in framework, not core. [Sharplab repro](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgdgpgLgZgHgGiiATgVzAHwAICYCMAsAFDYDMABHhQMIUDeJFzVuuDTLXAlmFBdwoBeCgFYA3Jy7Ns+AJwAKACQAieuu4gAIgF89KgJSTiXHSR1A==). If you switch from framework to x64, you'll get `{5}` as expected.

Comment: I can reproduce on `.NET Framework 4.7` as well.

Comment: I confirmed the issue on 4.8 as well. Seems you're looking at either disgusting hacks or moving to Core to get this to work as expected.